# Difference between stratifying in StratifiedKFold vs. train_test_split

Tags: scikit-learn

When training my model, I'm getting very different results when I use something like `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, train_size=0.9)` vs. `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)` and was wondering if there was a difference between how they stratified their data. I'm almost certain I implemented everything according to the docs, but strangely enough, the latter gives much worse testing accuracy than the first.

Comment: Can you post a minimal complete code which we can try and duplicate your behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

When `stratify` is not None `train_test_split` uses [StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn-model-selection-stratifiedshufflesplit) internally, not StratifiedKFold. So yeah, there is a big difference.

Comment: @hyperdo In addition, obvious difference is that StratifiedKFold will give 10 folds of different train and test data, and train_test_split will give only one.